# 500 Internal Error: Google Device Access API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, nest-api, nest-device-access

I am making the following request to generate an image url from a NEST Camera device ([documentation i'm following](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-event-image#request))

```
curl -X POST     'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/{PROJECTID}/devices/{DEVICEID}:executeCommand'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}'   --data-raw '{
    "command" : "sdm.devices.commands.CameraEventImage.GenerateImage",
      "params" : {"eventId" : "c4c58a0"}
}'
```

And I am met with the following error response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Whether or not I give a valid `eventId` I get this error response. There is no issues with my AUTH.

I have checked the status of Google's API and they're not reporting any downtime, I am sure the issue is something I am doing wrong, but can't figure out what.

Comment: did you check https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/errors/api

Comment: I just tried the same command (same format as you) and it worked.  A few things you can check... 1) What device model do you have?  Some models don't support snapshots. Check here https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/supported-devices  2) If a supported model, did you send the command within 30 seconds of receiving the event?  Snapshots expire in 30 seconds.  3) If a supported model, did you grant the camera snapshot permission for that device during account linking?